# Exact value or lower bound for $\sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}\sum\limits_{r=m}^{k} \frac1{r 2^r} {r \choose (m+r)/2}$

Tags: probability-distributions, summation

> How can I find the exact value or a tight upper bound when $m \to \infty$ for the sum
>   $$ F=  \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k}}{k!}\sum_{r=m}^{k} \frac{m}{r 2^r} {r \choose \frac{m+r}{2}}\ ? $$

Thus,
$$ F=me^{-\lambda}  \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}\sum_{r=m}^{k} \frac{1}{r 2^r} {r \choose \frac{m+r}{2}} $$
Note that
$$ F=  \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} Poisson(\lambda,k) \sum_{r=m}^{k} \mathbb{P}(r)$$
where 
$\displaystyle Poisson(\lambda,k)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k}}{k!}$, $\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(r)= \frac{m}{r 2^r} \binom{r}{\frac{m+r}{2}}$ is a probability.

Obviously, $m$ and $r$ should have the same parity. Therefore, we consider the  terms under the sum that $m$ and $r$ do not have the same parity, are equal to zero and ignore them.

Comment: as per your definition of $\mathrm{P}(r)$, $r \leq m$. From the two summations, you have $k \geq m$ and $r \geq k+1$, which contradict the above condition. Please check your limits of summation.

Comment: What is $Poisson(\lambda,k)$? Is it $e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k/k!$?

Comment: @Tadatmya Thanks for your comment, I simplified and corrected the problem statement.@Alex R. Yes, that is correct. I also corrected the problem statement.

Comment: What do you want when m+r is odd?

Comment: @martycohen Thanks for your comment, $m$ and $r$ should have the same parity. I added some notes about it in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

As we sum over positive numbers, we have $F_m \ge 0$ for all $m \ge 0$.
On the other hand, as $\mathbb{P}(r)$ is a probability distribution, we have $\sum_{r=m}^k \mathbb{P}(r) \le \sum_{r =0 }^\infty \mathbb{P}(r) = 1$. This yields
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} F_m = e^{-\lambda} \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{k=m}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \sum_{r=m}^k \mathbb{P}(r) \le e^{-\lambda} \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = 0$$
As $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = e^\lambda$, so the sum converges.
Thus $F \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is a comment,
but your question is unanswerable
until you deal with these problems.)

You have

$$F(m)
=  \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k}}{k!} \sum_{r=m}^{k}  \frac{r}{m 2^m} {m \choose \frac{m+r}{2}}
$$

But
${m \choose n} = 0$
for $n > m$,
so something is wrong with
your inner sum.

You need $r \le m$,
not $r \ge m$.

Do you mean
$\frac{r-m}{2}$?

Also,
you do not say what happens
when $m+r$ is odd.

Comment: I agree with you, I corrected the problem statement and added some comments about the parity of $m$ and $r$.